# Laravel Resource Routes Naming Prefix

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I've tow resource routes defined.

```
Route::resource('p/contacts', 'BaseData\PrivateContactsController');
Route::resource('b/contacts', 'BaseData\ContactController');
```

My Problem is that both resource group becomes the prefix same prefix (`contacts.show`, `contacts.edit`...)

In the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers#restful-naming-resource-routes) I found this way to name the routes

```
Route::resource('photos', 'PhotoController')->names([
'create' => 'photos.build'
]);
```

In my eyes this way is very complicated becaus I have to set the prefix for each single route. Is there a better way to set the prefix for all routes of the group?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Route::resource('p/contacts', 'BaseData\PrivateContactsController',["as"=>"private"]);
Route::resource('b/contacts', 'BaseData\ContactController',["as"=>"normal"]);
```

this way the urls will stay the same, but the names will have a prefix, for the first resource controller

```
private.contacts.index or private.contacts.edit
```

and for the second controller

```
    normal.contacts.create or normal.contacts.show
```

for more info check the documentation or this [github issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/13903)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'your_prefix'], function(){
    // put your code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the method route name like this

```
Route::resource('photos', 'PhotoController', [
    'names' => [
        'index' => 'photos',
        'store' => 'photos.new',
        // etc...
    ]
]);
```